# using errors in conditions in python

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, conditional-statements

I need help with my quadratic calculating program. I used an expression in an If, the expression will result in a math error obviously. But I don't want the code to break down when the error occurs instead, I want something else to happen.

```
import math


def quad(a, b, c):
    # creating a variable for all the parts that make the expression
    first_nu = int(a)
    second_nu = int(b)
    third_nu = int(c)
    four = 4
    two = 2
    det = second_nu ** 2 - (four * (first_nu * third_nu))

    if math.sqrt(det) == 0:
        print(' the discriminant is 0 hence the quadratic has no real roots')
    else:

        # calculating the roots
        root_det = math.sqrt(det)

        def printing():
            option1 = (-third_nu + root_det) / (two * first_nu)
            option2 = (-third_nu - root_det) / (two * first_nu)
            print(option1, option2)

        if det < 0:
            printing()
            print('The roots are not real roots')
        elif det == 0:
            print('mathematical error in a situation where there is root of 0')
            print('The roots has just one real root')
        elif det > 0:
            printing()
            print('The roots has two real roots')


first_num = input("enter your first number of the quadratic")
second_num = input("enter your second number of the quadratic")
third_num = input("enter your third number of the quadratic")

quad(first_num, second_num, third_num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **try:** on the code you want to test and put the rest of the code in **except**. I hope this will solve the issue. [For more information about Python error handling here](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/#:%7E:text=what%20you%20want%3F-,The%20try%20and%20except%20Block%3A%20Handling%20Exceptions,in%20the%20preceding%20try%20clause) or check from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

The `try` block lets you test a block of code for errors.

The `except` block lets you handle the error.

Comment: can you please send me a dummy code of what you mean?